# Is it possible to force touch in WPF to work like touch in WinForms?

Tags: wpf, winforms, touch

I created **WPF** application which allows user to interact with itself using touch. Unfortunately touch is working very bad when several instances of the same application are open.

I will try to describe the behaviour that I am facing:

1. Open two windows and place them right next to each other.
2. Touch left window with your finger and do not release it.
3. Any attempts to interact with the second window using touch will fail.

I have some experience of developing touch applications using **WinFroms**. And I never had such problems before. So I performed the described above trick with two WinForms applications and they are working just like they should - first window (with finger not released) keeps the focus but second window still allows user to perform clicks on its surface.

I also tried mixed combination - when WPF window is focused, WinFroms window still is touchable. But not the other way around - when WinForms window is focused, WPF window won't respond.

Is there anything that can be done to change described behaviour of the WPF windows?